# When, and by whom, was "$\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed" dubbed the "fundamental theorem of algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, math-history

Wikipedia has this enigmatic sentence on the page for the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra):

> ...its name was given at a time when the study of algebra was mainly concerned with the solutions of polynomial equations with real or complex coefficients.

While it sounds plausible, it begs the question:

> **Question**: In which time period did the title "fundamental theorem of algebra" get assigned to this theorem?  And who were the main contributors to this title?

Searching MathSciNet for "fundamental theorem of algebra" revealed:

> Bôcher, Maxime; *[Gauss's third proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183414404)*. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 1 (1895), no. 8, 205–209, [MR1557382](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1557382).

And by a Google Scholar search, I found this article, which mentions it in passing:

> William E. Story, *[A New Method in Analytic Geometry](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2369497)*, Amer. J. Math. 9, (1886), pp. 38-44.

However, it seems unlikely that these are the earliest references.

Comment: I was going to add (reference-request) to this question, but I'm not absolutely sure it's appropriate. Anyone else have an opinion?

Comment: Gauss himself called (an extension of) the fundamental theorem of algebra *[Grundlehrsatz der Theorie der algebraischen Gleichungen](http://archive.org/stream/werkecarlf03gausrich#page/n83/mode/2up)* in 1849.

Comment: @BenMillwood: I would have said it was definitely appropriate!

Comment: Fair enough. Also, if I was feeling super pedantic I might take issue with the questioner's use of "[begs the question](http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=693)".

Answer (score 5):

Try these references:

- Noel, Linda Hand:
  *The fundamental theorem of algebra: A survey of history and proofs.* 
  Thesis (Ed.D.)–Oklahoma State University. 1991. 202 pp. MR2687491 
  I couldn't find a copy online, just a [library entry](http://dc.library.okstate.edu/cdm/singleitem/collection/Dissert/id/7544/rec/7).
- Gilain, Christian:
  [Sur l'histoire du théorème fondamental de l'algèbre: théorie des équations et calcul intégral](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00496870).
  *Arch. Hist. Exact Sci.* 42 (1991), no. 2, 91–136. MR1118462 (92j:01034)

  It seems that Gauss was the first to use "the fundamental theorem of algebra" for a proposition by d'Alembert. Gilain cites Boyer's *History* here.
- Pla i Carrera, Josep:
  [The fundamental theorem of algebra before Carl Friedrich Gauss](http://dx.doi.org/10.5565/PUBLMAT_362B92_10).
  *Publ. Mat.* 36 (1992), no. 2B, 879–911 (1993). MR1210025 (94f:01021)

Comment: As a further reference on the fundamental theorem of algebra and its history I'd recommend Remmert's contribution in [chapter 4](http://books.google.com/books?id=OKcKowxXwKkC&pg=PA97) of *[Numbers](http://books.google.com/books?id=OKcKowxXwKkC)* (Ebbinghaus et al.).

Comment: Thanks for that.  The Gilian paper indeed quotes Boyer "...which Gauss later referred to as the fundamental theorem of algebra...".  (The book is in the library at Monash, so I'll be able to take a look tomorrow.)

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones, Boyer's book is freely available at http://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfMathematics.